# Which isolated DC - DC converter solution is better

Tags: dc-dc-converter

Based on suggestions by the previous question I cannot decide which DC-DC converter to use. The [SN6501](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn6501.pdf?ts=1592752041043&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FSN6501) paired with this [transformer](https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/750313626.pdf) for 5v to 5v operation or the [NXJ1](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8807031963678/kdc-nxj1.pdf?1583754813000).

My application is for this converter to power an ADC where the output of the converter will be feed to an ultra low noise LDO [LP5907](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp5907.pdf?ts=1592846282701&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F).

Here are my thoughts. The SN6501 for me already get points just for the fact that the datasheet shows applications of ADCs. Where the NXJ1 is appealing to me though is its smaller overall package, it seems to be not utilizing a transformer. Efficiency wise im not to concerned since i will only be using <= 100mA and the supply has ample of headroom (unless efficiency affects something else). Output ripple wise the NXJ1 has 20-50mV of ripple while the SN6501 does not say (since its only a driver). Isolation Wise both seems to be really good, since the circuit ultra worst cast 240V AC mains voltage (and its interfaced non-invasive so it not even connected). The NXJ1 can handle 4200V @1 minutes while the SN6501 coil's is 5000V @1 minute. about 20x safety factor.

I would like to hear what do you think, and which one would you choose performance wise, ingore cost. Im leaning to the NXJ1 just for its size, but if SN6501 performs even slightly better i will switch.

Comment: Tricky choice. I would swing towards the murata part despite me pointing you to the texas part for no other reason than it's an all-in-one solution. It will have isolating magnetics of course but they are just not visible in the picture. On the other hand, it's much more likely that you'll be able to get the TI chip for a long. long time and, there are many magnetics providers who will step up to the bar if need be. What about PCB footprint usage?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about your requirements we can't give a precise answer. It depends on your signal to noise ratio coming in, filtering, ADC converter, # of bits, post conversion filtering, ADC PSRR, what else is powered by that supply line, just how good to you need it. etc?

For example you might not care at all about noise near the switching frequency of the converter. The noise rejection of the ADC might be plenty. Or, you might care a whole lot because you're trying to detect a very low level signal with high precision in a way in your system such that switching noise is killing you.

You may not care at all about load transient response of the regulator because it never sees much. Or, you might be hitting it with a big current slug and then you have to take an ADC reading during the recovery and it's impacting your results.

The Murata part doesn't seem to have much for data. They're a tier 1 company who knows power so I'd bet they make a good part, but only data will tell.

The SN part looks generally solid as well.

My suggestion is to buy the Murata module and focusing on the signal chain. You'll learn at some point if you have power supply requirements and will have to address them at that point. Rolling your own with the SN part is fine but seems like extra effort without yet knowing whether it's beneficial.

You may not need a linear reg to filter noise at all. But I'd leave room for one in case you do.

Comment: The current plan is to just straight hook them straight up plus capacitors just like the SN5901 sample circuits (no inductors as they take so much space).The ADC i chose is a 24bit  one with 78-100 dB of PSRR. Im sure that i wont be able to get the full 24bits . But im going to give the ADC is best chance. There is nothing else powered on that line exept for an LED at 3mA (hooked before the LDO).

Comment: For you good sir which one will you pick if you wanted the best for your adc?